# Why is firefox running in background even when uninstalled?

Tags: firefox

I have uninstalled firefox and also removed `.mozilla` dir from home dir. These processes come up instantly even after they are `kill`ed. How to determine what is creating these processes? They keep using CPU upto 40-50% when viewed in `htop`.

```
~$ ps -aux | grep firefox
shubham  2883387 13.2  3.5 2662844 271024 ?      Ssl  23:36   0:04 /usr/bin/firefox --no-remote --headless about:blank --remote-debugging-port=0 --profile /tmp/puppeteer_dev_firefox_profile-dFaLal
shubham  2883441  3.9  1.7 2415508 134416 ?      Sl   23:36   0:01 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 1 -prefMapSize 232908 -jsInit 278944 -parentBuildID 20211102211617 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 18 tab
shubham  2883461  1.9  1.2 2382880 96640 ?       Rl   23:36   0:00 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 85 -prefMapSize 232908 -jsInit 278944 -parentBuildID 20211102211617 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 18 tab
```

Comment: do you recognize "puppeteer dev firefox profile"? what else are you running on the pc?

Comment: What release of Ubuntu is this? And how exactly did you uninstall Firefox?  Also please add to your question the complete output of `snap list firefox` and of `apt list firefox`

Comment: Programs that are already running aren't stopped by an uninstall, or by removal of the binary. A running program has all it needs in its process. Use `pkill -9 firefox`.

Comment: @Esther I don't recognize puppeteer, other things running (suspecting them) are qBittorrent web UI, trilium notes (node js), pi-hole. Also, there's no file `/usr/bin/firefox` or `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't actually figure out how to know who created the process or ran the `/usr/bin/firefox` command. But a docker container was running, so tried stopping and deleting it, and it worked.